# Regular expression, replace 2 or more consecutive identical characters in SQL

Tags: sql, regex, apache-spark, hive

With regular expression I would like to replace 2 or more consecutive identical characters by only one occurrence of this character.
Ex: eeee => e

I want to achieve this in hive through the regexp_replace function.

I tried:

```
regexp_replace("aaeebb", "(.)\\1{1,}", "\\1")
```

which is working with the gsub R function but not with regexp_replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala:

- Raw SQL

  ```scala
  sqlContext.sql("""SELECT regexp_replace('aaeebb', '(.)\\1+', '$1')""")
  ```
- DSL

  ```scala
  df.select(regexp_replace(lit("aaeebb"), "(.)\\1+", "$1"))
  ```

PySpark:

- Raw SQL

  ```py
  sqlContext.sql("""SELECT regexp_replace('aaeebb', '(.)\\\\1+', '$1')""")
  # or
  sqlContext.sql(r"""SELECT regexp_replace('aaeebb', '(.)\\1+', '$1')""").show()
  ```
- DSL

  ```py
  df.select(regexp_replace(lit("aaeebb"), "(.)\\1+", "$1"))
  ```

Spark SQL shell:

```sql
SELECT regexp_replace('aaeebb', '(.)\\1+', '$1');
```

Hive shell:

```sql
SELECT regexp_replace('aaeebb', '(.)\\1+', '$1');
```